# Finding REGEX for this Expression(javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string in java script

```
href="http://site.com/colours/254359457969591" title="hello"
```

I need to get the value 254359457969591 from the above href string.I tried with many methods. Can anybody guide me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Well, just `/\d+/` would work in this example.

Comment: var val = data.match(data.match(/colours/(\d+)/));
i tried this its not working

Comment: and i have more numbers in the string...i need to find value between colours/ and " title

Comment: There lies the importance of being specific in your question. By all rights I answered the question, but because you didn't tell us enough the answer was actually wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "href=\"http://site.com/colours/254359457969591\" title=\"hello\"";
var result = /href="http:\/\/site.com\/colours\/(\d+)"/.exec(s);
var num = result[1];
```

The result of `num` is: `254359457969591`

Comment: @JustinBiaber - fixed.  (Made a quick edit to account for your other comments, and made a typo...)

Comment: why did u put \ before "http sir?

Comment: @JustinBiaber - because I'm declaring this value within JavaScript, I'm escaping the quotes (has nothing to do with the "http").  (Alternatively, I could have cheated and just used single quotes, so that the double-quotes didn't need to be escaped.)

Answer (score 0):

```
m/href="http:\/\/site\.com/colours/([0-9]+)/i
```

`$1` is the number.

Just use the javascript provided regex functions and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would get it with javascript's [Match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function:

```
str = 'href="http://site.com/colours/254359457969591" title="hello"';
patt1 = /\d+/;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

### UPDATE

If you want to get the numbers between colours/ and " then use this regex:

```
/colours\/(\d+)"/
```

Here's the match function updated:

```
str = 'href="http://site.com/colours/254359457969591" title="hello"';
patt1 = /colours\/(\d+)"/;
document.write(str.match(patt1)[1]);
```

Comment: actually i have more numbers in string..i need tto find it between the colours/ and "